# How do I open my inventory in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I'm at the first main combat section of the game and all I have is a pistol. I've killed a guy and picked up his machine gun, but I can't seem to find the key to open my inventory to equip it.

Is there an inventory that lets me equip the weapon? If so, what's the default keybinding?

Edit: I should clarify that pressing I doesn't work. And opening the keybinds shows the controller

Comment: Have you looked through the key bindings/mappings section of the Settings in game?

Answer (score 3):

On a PC, the default keybinding to open your inventory is the <kbd>**i**</kbd> key. From there you can equip weapons and use the mouse wheel to switch between them.

Comment: Guess its his 1st PC game and he missed the tutorial lol. Because i for Inventory is pretty much the default with games that have an inventory to speak of.

Comment: @Fredy31 I don't actually remember the game explaining how to open inventory, I think I tried several of the keys to see what they do when the game first gave me control of my character. But you are right, i is pretty standard for inventory.

Comment: @Fredy31: B for 'bags' isn't uncommon either (WoW for one, but other games did it too), but I is the most common iirc.

Comment: I doesn't work. I can't find the keybinds section either

Comment: It's okay. I've just been using an Xbox controller in the meantime

Comment: @Ben If you have never found the keybindings (and thus by extension never changed them), then `i` most certainly will work. Unless your `i` key on your keyboard is broken. If you are playing on console then you should specify that in your question.

Comment: I'm not playing on console. I'm playing on PC, the steam version if that helps. I have an Xbox controller that works. The PC controls do work, the I key works normally, it just doesn't open the inventory